# How to traverse through all elements of json using robotframework and fetch only those that match the query

Tags: json, robotframework

I am trying to extract a node from a json file for a json element that matches another node in same element.
To be more specific, I want the names of all students in the sample json below who has "certified":"false"

```
Example JSON
{
    "Students": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "Rank": "1",
            "certified":"false"
        },
        {

            "name": "Ashley",
            "Rank": "5",
            "certified":"true"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code i am using is (gives me empty output) :

```
Library    JSONLibrary

JSON_Verification
    [Documentation]    Testing JSON load logic
    ${metadataJson_object}=    Load JSON From File    ../TestData/sample.json
    Log    ${metadataJson_object}
    @{studentName}=    Get Value From Json    ${metadataJson_object}    "$..[?(@.certified=='false')]@.name"
    Log @{studentName}
```

Comment: What does the code you're using now do, and how is that different from what you want?

Comment: @BryanOakley it gives me empty output

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you were very close to it, `@` notation is not needed after filter. Just change the json path to =
`$.Students[?(@.certified=='false')].name`

Here :
`$` -> root element
`.` -> child operator or to access the property
`?()` -> filter expression and
`@` -> current node

```
${json}=      Convert String to JSON    ${Getjson}
${name}=      Get Value From Json         ${json}        $.Students[?(@.certified=='false')].name
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I tried changing the jsonpath to "$.Students[?(@.certified=='false')].name". Still getting empty output. I think it is because "Load JSON From File " gives me a dictionary and not a json.

Comment: {JSON_Verification_sample
    [Documentation]    Testing JSON load logic
    ${metadataDict_object}=    Load JSON From File    ../TestData/sample.json
    Log    ${metadataDict_object}
    ${studentName}=    Get Value From Json    ${metadataDict_object}    "$.Students[?(@.certified=='false')].name"
    :FOR    ${name}    IN    @{studentName}
    \    Log    ${name}
    ${length}    get length    ${metadataDict_object["Students"]}
    log    ${length}

Comment: I tried with your code it should return you `John` as value

Comment: I am receiving empty output. Jus wondering how to attach screenshots in comments here

Comment: There is no way to attach screenshot in the comments also it is bad practice to attach screenshot

Comment: Can you sent the output of this line `Log    ${metadataJson_object}`?

Comment: This is the output
INFO {'Students': [{'name': 'John', 'Rank': '1', 'certified': 'false'}, {'name': 'Ashley', 'Rank': '5', 'certified': 'true'}]}

Comment: This is what i get when i get students name with condition::
INFO ${studentName} = []

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure what you looking for. everything is there in the answer, if you have any doubt ask different question with all details. if single things misses out that could lead you to different solution so make sure you add all details in question. Also read [mcve] and follow that

Comment: ok, I will create a new question all together with more details.
Thanks!